# Transaction still commits after violation of unique constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that is in this format (simplified):

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION myTransaction
--multiple CRUD operations
--insert statement inserts records into table with unique constraint.

    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
      BEGIN     
        COMMIT TRANSACTION myTransaction
        RAISERROR ('TRANSACTION COMMITTED', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
        RETURN 1
      END
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
      BEGIN
        SELECT
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION myTransaction
        RAISERROR ('TRANSACTION ROLLED BACK', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
        RETURN 0
      END
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
      BEGIN         
        COMMIT TRANSACTION myTransaction
        RAISERROR ('TRANSACTION COMMITTED', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
        RETURN 1
      END
END CATCH
```

I'm trying to address an issue where the SP tries to insert records into a table with a unique constraint, and it fails, so it doesn't insert anything.  The problem is, this doesn't seem to trigger the catch block, or change the XACT_STATE() to reflect that there's a problem.  What am I doing wrong?

The desired functionality would be that if the constraint is violated, the entire transaction would fail and be rolled back.

Comment: why would you add a commit mechanism in the catch block?

Comment: Because as I understand it, there are scenarios where the transaction is in a commitable state, but that the catch block would be triggered.  I can't remember where I got that information, or what scenario would cause that. I read it in on the internet, which as you know, is infallible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have over complicated a fairly simple task, I would just scrap the XACT_ABORT() function altogether and simply sitck to try..catch block. something like ......

```
BEGIN TRY
         BEGIN TRANSACTION myTransaction
--multiple CRUD operations
--insert statement inserts records into table with unique constraint.


-- if an error occurs in any of the above statements the control will
-- jump to Catch block and the Commit trans never gets executed
        COMMIT TRANSACTION myTransaction

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION myTransaction
    END

        SELECT
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage

END CATCH
```

Answer (score 6):

As you're using

```
Set Xact_Abort On
```

My understanding is that the transaction has ALREADY been rolled back by the time you get to any Catch part. There is nothing to rollback.

There's also something I seem to remember about there being times when such an instance would bypass the Catch altogether.

Comment: That could have something to do with it.  When I originally wrote this code, I didn't have XACT_ABORT ON.   I added that bit of code today, so that may have caused issues..